# Are triple quotation marks unicode characters according to python

Tags: python, unicode, skulpt

I'm trying to use triple quotes to designate a large comment, but I'm getting a new error that says

SyntaxError: invalid string (possibly contains a unicode character) on line 2

Here's the code.

```
"""

Write a program that asks the user how many names they have. 
(If they have a first name, two middle names, and a last 
name, for example, they would type 4.) Then, using a for 
loop, ask the user for each of their names. Finally, print 
their full name.

"""
```

The triple quotes that I'm having a problem with are the ones at the top.

With that information out of the way, my question is "Are triple quotation marks unicode characters according to python?"

If this is a repeat post, feel free to move it.

Comment: Have you tried removing the entire multi-line comment (including the quotation marks) and then retyping it from scratch in your editor?

Comment: Don't use strings as comments, use `#` on each line.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this in a module that you import into another script? Depending on your setup, an old version of the module that did contain some kind of error might still be cached. The snippet you have given does not throw an error.

Comment: Well, _every_ character is a Unicode character. But the triple quotes are just three single `"` characters, which are ASCII as well as Unicode, and so shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The code you posted here is entirely ASCII safe. Note that ASCII is a *subset of Unicode*, so ASCII codepoints are also Unicode codepoints.

Comment: If they _are_ a problem, it's not because they're tripled, but because the individual quote characters are not ASCII quotes.

Comment: What version of python and what platform? Be specific.

Comment: I thought they were ASCII, but the python compiler that I have to use for this class has other ideas. (@roganjosh I copy and pasted the instructions for the class into the compiler.) (@ndmeiri I'll try that.)

Comment: @Daniel I think this is his module docstring. If so, although it would probably be better to rewrite it into what the program actually does instead of what the assignment was, it's not that unreasonable to put it into the docstring as-is. (Calling a docstring a "comment" in the answer, on the other hand, isn't as reasonable, but it's an understandable beginner mistake.)

Comment: https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt/blob/master/src/ast.js#L1782

Comment: Is the `"""` the first line of the file? If so, line 2 is that blank line—which may not actually be blank, but have some non-printing non-ASCII character in it?

Comment: This isn't a CPython syntax error, the error is unique to Skulpt.

Comment: Thanks Martin... I switched to hashtags, which fixed the problem.

Comment: `#` is a hash mark; `#foo` is a hashtag, a string that starts with a hash mark.

Comment: Or is it? `'\N{NUMBER SIGN}' == '#'` :^)

Comment: The error means that the malformed string *starts* on line 2.  It does not mean that `"""` is the problem.  There presumably is some non-ASCII character (possibly whitespace) somewhere else within that string.  Try deleting parts of the string to isolate it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the provided characters are [all valid ASCII characters](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%22%22%22%0D%0A%0D%0AWrite+a+program+that+asks+the+user+how+many+names+they+have.+%0D%0A%28If+they+have+a+first+name%2C+two+middle+names%2C+and+a+last+%0D%0Aname%2C+for+example%2C+they+would+type+4.%29+Then%2C+using+a+for+%0D%0Aloop%2C+ask+the+user+for+each+of+their+names.+Finally%2C+print+%0D%0Atheir+full+name.%0D%0A%0D%0A%22%22%22) (The [Basic Latin Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)) just happens to have the exact same character set as ASCII). So this should not cause any issues in a standard Python interpreter like [CPython](https://www.python.org/) or [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/) (regardless whether it's Python 2 or 3).

> Are triple quotation marks Unicode characters according to Python?

Technically all ASCII characters are included in Unicode, but what I think you're really asking is "Are triple quotation marks non-ASCII characters?", to which the answer is "No". They're just three [QUOTATION MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm) (`"`) in a row.

```py
>>> for c in '"""':
...     print('Character:', repr(c))
...
Character: '"'
Character: '"'
Character: '"'
```

You can also check this pretty easily in Python 3.7+ using the [`str.isascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isascii#str.isascii) method:

```py
>>> '"""'.isascii()
True
>>> '""☺'.isascii()
False
```

It used to be that to use Unicode literals in your source files you would need to include a [special comment in the first or second line](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) of your source files (e.g. `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`), but as of Python 3 [source files default to using UTF-8](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code).